# SASS not compiling in media query order

Tags: css, sass

So I've made the following mixins and using them in the particular order, but they do not work as intended to.

```
@mixin mediaX {
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
    @content;
  }
}

//iPhone 6,7,8
@mixin media6 {
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) {
    @content;
  }
}

//iPhone 6,7,8 Plus
@mixin media6Plus {
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) {
    @content;
  }
}

//iPhone 5 and 5S
@mixin media5 {
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

and usage is following

```
@include mediaX {
  .navigation {
    text-align: justify;
  }
}

@include media6Plus {
  .navigation {
    text-align: justify;
  }
}

@include media6 {
  .navigation {
    text-align: justify;
  }
}

@include media5 {
  .navigation {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

It appears that only `media5` is only reflecting, can someone explain what is wrong and why it is working like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a conflict in rules based on the screen sizes in your above media queries. Hence the last one is the only rule that is getting applied by default. I have never written a media query based on the device I usually write it base on screen size. Make sure you write media query based on screen sizes and not based on devices as media query can only pick on screen sizes and not devices.

Make media queries like these.

```
//screen size 1200px and above
@mixin media6 {
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 1200px) {
        @content;
        }
    }
//media query between 1200px and 992px
@mixin media6Plus {
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 992px) and (max-device-width: 
  1199px) {
    @content;
  }
}

And then use them like this 
@include media6 {
  .navigation {
    text-align: justify;
  }
}

@include media6Plus {
  .navigation {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but these media queries are supposed for only Apple devices based screen sizes reference : http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ so there must be something in the order of the media queries, right?

Comment: As I said, the media queries need to be based on screen size and not devices. So you should write the queries according to screen sizes. So you might wanna set the alignments according to screen sizes and not the type of device. The reference example you gave is based if you are working on one of the devices specifically. I really hope this helps :)

Comment: chaturvedi can you demonstrate what you're trying to say? thanks